# How to get nested rows in dataTables JavaScript plugin?

Tags: datatables

I'm using the datatables.net JavaScript plugin, and I'm using ajax to bring the data with json.
Here is the JavaScript code to create the table:

```js
function buildDataTableAjax(tableId, dataUrl) {
table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
          processing: true
          , serverSide: true
          , ajax: dataUrl
          , deferRender: true
          , responsive: true
          , pageLength: 15
          , lengthMenu: [[15, 30, 50], [15, 30, 50]]
     });
}
```

This works fine for an ordinary table, but now I need nested tables (e.g. on each row I need to have a nested table of extra data).
I found some examples (http://jsfiddle.net/86nBA/5/, http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/zz3cH/) that shows nested tables, but I need a way to accomplish it with the ajax approach I'm using to bring the data.

Is there a way in which I can build the json for the datatable to include a nested table ? If not, how can I add the nested tales under the correct rows ?

Comment: It is called row details -> https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html you dont need specific JSON, you can insert anything, like HTML.

Comment: Great :-) If you could please just add it as an answer so that I could mark it as solved...

Comment: Dont think a link qualifies to an accepted answer :) But if you want a certain example of using row details I could perhaps produce that.

Comment: That would be great :-)

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, but it works only if I have 1 datatable in a page. When I have 2 (or more) it doesn't work... any ideas why ?

Comment: If you havent figured it out yet :  please show the markup / HTML - then I think it should be possible to debug why it is not working for you.